# find all numbers disappeared in array

Tags: javascript

Please help me to solve this leetcode problem using javascript  as I am a beginner and dont know why this code is  not working

Ques: Given an array of integers where 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array), some elements appear twice and others appear once.

Find all the elements of [1, n] inclusive that do not appear in this array.

```js
var findDisappearedNumbers = function (nums) {
    var numLength = nums.length;
    nums.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        if (nums[i + 1] === nums[i]) {
            nums.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < nums.length; k++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= numLength; j++) {
            if (nums[k] !== j) {
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

if there is any error in my code please let me know;

i have done the following thing

first i have sorted the array in ascending order
then i have cut all the duplicate elements
then i have created loop that will check if nums[k] !== j ;
and it will return j which is the missing number;

for example this  is the testcase [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
first my code will sort this in ascending order [1,2,2,3,3,4,7,8]

then it will remove all duplicate elements and it will return [1,2,3,4,,7,8]
and then it will check nums[k] is not equal to j and it will print j

Comment: If it is a leetcode problem you should probably use their discussion forums

Answer (score 3):

I think it'd be easier to create a Set of numbers from 1 to `n`, then just iterate through the array and delete every found item from the set:

```js
var findDisappearedNumbers = function(nums) {
  const set = new Set();
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    set.add(i + 1);
  }
  for (const num of nums) {
    set.delete(num);
  }
  return [...set];
};

console.log(findDisappearedNumbers([4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]));
```

To fix your existing code, I'm not sure what the logic you're trying to implement in the lower section, but you can iterate from 1 to `numLength` (in the outer loop, not the inner loop) and check to see if the given number is anywhere in the array. Also, since you're mutating the array with `splice` while iterating over it in the upper loop, make sure to subtract one from `i` at the same time so you don't skip an element.

```js
var findDisappearedNumbers = function(nums) {
  var numLength = nums.length;
  nums.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
    if (nums[i + 1] === nums[i]) {
      nums.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  const notFound = [];
  outer:
  for (var j = 1; j < numLength; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < nums.length; k++) {
      if (nums[k] === j) {
        continue outer;
      }
    }
    notFound.push(j);
  }
  return notFound;
};

console.log(findDisappearedNumbers([4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 2, 3, 1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

@CertainPerformance certainly cracked it again using the modern `Set` class. Here is a slighly more conservative approach using an old fashioned object:

```js
console.log(missingIn([4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]));

function missingIn(arr){
  const o={};
  arr.forEach((n,i)=>o[i+1]=1    );
  arr.forEach((n)  =>delete o[n] );
  return Object.keys(o).map(v=>+v);
}
```

Comment: Your output is returning array of strings. OP is expecting numbers.

Comment: @RahulBhobe: Just fixed it with a short `.map(v=>+v)`!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the problem to find the missing element

```
var findDisappearedNumbers = function(nums) {
const map={};
const result=[];

for(let a=0;a<nums.length;a++){
    map[nums[a]]=a;      
}

for(let b=0;b<nums.length;b++){
    if(map[b+1]===undefined){
        result.push(b+1)
    }    
}

return result;
};
```

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
Output: [5,6]
```

Example 2:

```
Input: nums = [1,1]
Output: [2]
```